# Can these nested if-then-else be turned into a boolean formula?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have this logic statement:

```
    (A and x) or (B and y) or (not (A and B) and z)
```

The problem is that accessing A and B are rather expensive. Therefore I'd like to access them only once each.  I can do this with an if-then-else construct:

```
if A then
  if x then
    true
  endif
else
  if B then
    if y then
      true
    endif
  else
    if z then
      true
    endif
  endif
endif
```

Is there a way to express this as a boolean expression?  I have "and", "or" (both short-circuit) but no "xor".

I thought this would work:

```
X and (A or (Y and (B xor Z)))
```

But my test program (http://pastebin.com/EjURvpM4) shows it doesn't.

Comment: An "if" statement "if A then B" has the same truth table as "not A or B".  Does this help change your "if then else" sequence into "and" and "or" logic?

Comment: @abiessu: The "if" in the question is not logical implication but a selection operator, which is something completely different.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that may be true, but in programming the two often have the same effect, especially with short-circuit compilers.

Comment: @abiessu: No, if-then-else is a completely different thing. One can _simulate_ logical implication "$A\to B$" by "if A then B else true", but that is just incidental.

Comment: @henningmakholm I see your point

Comment: @henningmakholm however, given that the original statement is non-implication-based and can be written in if-then-else form, it is appropriate to consider the "not A or B" substitution.

Comment: @TomOnTime Since you seem to be using Python, why use a _boolean_ expression?  You can just write `x if A else y if B else z`?

Comment: @TomOnTime Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic idea is to then always check x, y, z before A and B. Given the short-circuiting of "and" and "or", here's an expression that will never evaluate A and B more than once:

```
(x or y) and z or (x and A) or (y and B) or z and not (A and B)
```

where the order of precedence from highest to lowest is: not, and, or.

Comment: I verified the logical correctness of this formula by plugging `!A,B,x,y,z.(TRUE => ((A & x) or (B & y) or ((not (A & B)) & z) <=> ((x or y) & z) or (x & A) or (y & B) or (z & not (A & B))))` into the [ProB](http://www.stups.uni-duesseldorf.de/ProB/index.php5/ProB_Logic_Calculator) on-line tautology checker.

Comment: That's brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

If it's more important to optimize execution time than lines of code, then you might want to stick with an if-else tree. If `z and (x or y)` then you can return `true` without having to evaluate either A or B. Similarly, if `not (x or y or z)` then you can return `false`. If `x and not (y or z)`, then you only have to evaluate A; if `y and not (x or z)`, then you only have to evaluate B.